# deeplinking into other apps from current app in samsung tizen tv

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am writing an app for a Samsung Smart TV running Tizen. My app shows a list of curated Hotstar titles. When the user clicks, my app should launch the Hotstar app and have it start playing that title. According to the documentation, the code should look something like this.

The format of the PAYLOAD isn't specified, and the settings for some other values (such as "uri") aren't clear.

Can anybody help me with sample code that deep links?

```
let uri = null;
let payload = {values: JSON.stringify({videoIdx: 'https://www.netflix.com/watch/80219127'})};
let data = new tizen.ApplicationControlData('PAYLOAD', [JSON.stringify(payload)]);
let appControl = new tizen.ApplicationControl('http://tizen.org/appcontrol/operation/view',
                                              uri, null, null, [data], null);
tizen.application.launchAppControl(
    appControl,
    href,
    param => console.log('launch success', param),
    error => console.log('launch error', error.message)
);
```

Comment: I just fixed the typesetting for you, please take care of that next time.

Comment: @B--rian How did u fixed it

Comment: @PiyushAggarwal I fixed *the typesetting of the question*, not the issue.

Comment: Anybody who has fixed the issue